# Updating view after promise resolved from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I am using Laravel as my back-end, serving as an API for user auth and any CRUD operations. I can't seem to get this implementation of user auth on the angular side working. What I want is just the user to be loaded from the API by the call to fetchUser(), then the user can be retrieved from getUser(). I am not using Angular for routing so I can't make it render only when resolved. I figured by using promises Angular would automatically update the view. I guess I don't understand the whole digest process because nothing I do makes the view change after the user is loaded. A simple `ng-show="user.$resolved"` or even `ng-show="user"` doesn't work. The page stays as it was before the promise was resolved. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? Or maybe a better way to implement this? I'm not too worried about security, it is not a very functional website. Just an API object I can fetch to display the page a certain way if they are logged in and what role they are.

controllers.js

```
var Controllers = new angular.module("Controllers", []);

Controllers.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$location", "Auth", "$timeout", function($scope, $location, Auth, $timeout) {

    $scope.user = Auth.fetchUser().then(function(data) {
        $scope.user = data;
        console.log(data);
    });

}]);
```

services.js

```
Services.factory("Auth", function($http, $q) {

    var user;

    function getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    function fetchUser() {
    return $http.get("api/auth").then(function(response) {
        if (response.data.user) {
            user = response.data.user;
        } else {
            user = null;
        }
        return user;
    });
}

    return {
        getUser: getUser,
        fetchUser: fetchUser
    };

});
```

master.blade.php

```
<div class="container">

    @include("layouts/nav")

    @yield("content")

</div>
```

nav.blade.php (partial)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="/inquire">Inquire</a></li>
    <li ng-show="user.$resolved && user.id"><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li ng-show="user.$resolved && user.role === 'User'"><a href="/admin/dashboard">Admin</a></li>
    <li ng-hide="user.$resolved && user.id"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li ng-hide="user.$resolved && user.id"><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

When the user is logged in, login and register only show as if the user has not been loaded/logged in yet.

Comment: The obvious thing is that you're using [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) instead of just returning $http promise. Deferred will just make a promise unsettled here. And you don't mention if console.log fires or not.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I was returning `$http.get.then()` before, this was a different attempt. Still resulted in the same thing. I will switch it back. The console.log() works fine, if the user is logged in it is the user object, if not it is undefined. Problem is the view doesn't reflect that because it renders before the user is loaded.

Comment: The view reflects the changes in scope, that's how data binding works. It is re-rendered when `user` is updated. `user` assignment occurs during the digest cycle and shouldn't be the problem, the problem is elsewhere. I would suggest to recreate [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as fiddle/plunker, this may help.

Comment: Why do you expect to find a `$resolved` property on your `user` object? You aren't using `ngResource`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, you're returning the entire response object in the `$http` promise resolver. You've also fallen prey to the deferred promise anti-pattern by wrapping a promise based API (`$http`) in a deferred object.

Try this...

```
function fetchUser() {
    return $http.get('api/auth').then(function(response) {
        if (response.data.user) {
            return response.data.user;
        }
        return $q.reject('No user data');
    });
}
```

and

```
Auth.fetchUser().then(function(data) {
    $scope.user = data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: My apologies, I had it this way before. The `$q` implementation resulted in the same thing but I didn't like the look of it either. Found it on the internet, figured I'd try it. The updated code results in the same thing. The code works fine as for fetching the user, the view just does not update.

Comment: @Jordan so what does your view look like?